# Material UI Card Size on PC is different on Mobile

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a single page application and I am satisfied with how it looks like on my laptop's screen. However, when I tried to run the web app on mobile it is very different.

I am using Material UI on ReactJS, and here's what it looks like on my PC: [image: PC]

And here is how it looks on mobile:

[image: Mobile]

I do not understand why the cards (from Material UI) are being shrunk and shifted to the right while the media (img) in the card is the same. Here's my code for the Card's Style:

```
var cardStyle = {
width: '30vw',
transitionDuration: '0.3s',
height: '27vw',
boxShadow: "3px 3px 3px black",
}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant, but here's the media's style:

```
media: {
height: 'auto',
width: 'auto',
paddingTop: '52.6%'
}
```

Here's the total code for that page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import { db } from "../firebase";
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import { GridListTile } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = theme =>({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    paddingTop: '52.6%'
  },
});

    var cardStyle = {

  width: '30vw',
  transitionDuration: '0.3s',
  height: '27vw',
   boxShadow: "3px 3px 3px black",
}

var styles = {
  body: {
     backgroundImage : 'url("nature.jpg")',
     backgroundSize: "cover",
     backgroundPosition: "center",
     backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
 
 }
}     

class Games extends Component  {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
   gameKeys: " "
};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    for(var i in styles.body){
      document.body.style[i] = styles.body[i];
      }

    db.getGame().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let newStates = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          newStates.push({
          value: childSnapshot.val().value,
          label: childSnapshot.val().label,
          image: childSnapshot.val().image,
          platform: childSnapshot.val().platform,
          genre: childSnapshot.val().genre,
          date: childSnapshot.val().date, 
          dlc: childSnapshot.val().dlc,
          id: childSnapshot.val().id
      });
  });
  this.setState({
      gameKeys: newStates
  });
});
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
for(var i in styles.body){
    document.body.style[i] = null;
}
  }
  render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
            
    <div >
      
     <GridList cols={2} cellHeight="auto" spacing='50' style={{paddingTop: '70px'}} >
      {Object.keys(this.state.gameKeys).map((key, index) => 
        <GridListTile key={key}>
        <Card style={cardStyle}>
         <CardActionArea>
         <CardMedia 
          className={classes.media}
          image={this.state.gameKeys[key].image}
          title={this.state.gameKeys[key].value}
        />
      <CardContent>
      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
      {this.state.gameKeys[key].value}
      </Typography>
      <Typography  variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" >
      <b style={{alignItems:"left"}}>Genre:</b> {' '+ this.state.gameKeys[key].genre + ' '} <br/>
      <b>Platform:</b> {' '+ this.state.gameKeys[key].platform + ' '}   <br/>      <b>Release Date: </b> {' '+ this.state.gameKeys[key].date + ' '}
      <br/> <b>DLC:</b>  {' '+ this.state.gameKeys[key].dlc}  
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
    <br/><br/>
    </GridListTile>
    
      )}
    </GridList>
    

    </div>
  );
  }
}

Games.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Games);
```

Comment: That's why it is recommended *mobile first* pattern. Would you share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Kinda hard to do it since I'm using firebase, I have to link it and then do routes again.

Comment: If your github repository is public, you may share that (codesandbox may import and deploy your source code into live environment)

Comment: I don't have it on github either. However, I just hosted it on firebase, you can view it hands on and inspect element I guess, hope that helps. https://techwiki-dace3.web.app/games

Comment: You've got a `div.jss11` that has a static width of 240px (which takes up a lot of space on mobile) and your `main` has a right margin of 170px. This is most of the real estate on a mobile screen. You need to fix your surrounding css to get this looking the way you want.

Comment: Oh that actually really helped me, I didn't notice them taking space, I might've used them as a test and actually forgot they were there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing your static height and width (by pixel) settings on the surrounding elements and taking another look at your height and width settings on the grid tiles, Cards, and papers within the cards will fix your issue. I removed all of those (and changed the display type to 'grid') and it resulted in this:

[image]

You also need to add some media queries so that you can column things out and size things up differently depending on the size of the screen you're dealing with.

My recommendation would also be to rethink the static margin on the left side of the screen that's saved for your menu. I would consider making the menu take up the entire screen on mobile while overlaying your content on desktop.

Comment: When I removed the column from Grid and made the width and height of the cards Auto, it looks perfect on the phone but too huge on the PC. Is there a way to keep the look on the phone but change the PC view?